# How can I install vcrun2008 using Winetricks?

Tags: wine, winetricks

I tried to install `vcrun2008` but i always get

`vcrun2008 install completed, but installed file`
`/home/bla/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/winsxs/x86_Microsoft.VC90.MFC_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_x-ww_028bc148/mfc90.dll not found`

I installed winetricks from the Ubuntu Software Center, then i read about manual install and installed it manually into my home directory. But the manual install is not active when I uninstall the Ubuntu Software Center version.

How can i install the latest version from Ubuntu Software Center? Or how can i install vcrun2008 with the USC?

Answer (score 3):

You can add `vcrun2008`, or any other Windows component or `.dll`, using Winetricks.

- Open Winetricks
- Select the profile that you want to add the `.dll` to (e.g. the default)
- Select "Install a Windows DLL or component"; click OK
- Select the component(s) you want installed; click OK
- Follow the handy dialog boxes

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install it using USC.

You can download the required dll from [dll-files.com](http://www.dll-files.com/), and then simply copy it into the C:\Windows folder (within the WINE directory).

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was failing even with winetricks, the 'new trick' is to temporarily change it with winecfg to windowsXP, install vcrun2008 and then back to ex windows7 (default now)